# Open datasets like the GigaWord for text summarization?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

The [English GigaWord dataset](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2003T05) by the Linguistics Dataset Consortium contains some 10 million articles alongside an equally large vocabulary set. It's a *lot* of organised data. If I had to say it less formally, I'd call it every data scientist's wet dream.

However, it costs a non-member $3000 to obtain.

You heard me. *Three grands*.

The CNN and DailyMail data that DeepMind uses [here](https://github.com/deepmind/rc-data) sizes up to some 300,000 articles which is a mere 30% which would reflect by a similar proportion in terms of learning.

Might be a long-shot but are there any large open datasets which could be used for the purpose of text summarization?

Comment: by my calculation it's 3%